# How Charlie and his team convert gold into car in such a short time span in Players?

Tags: plot-explanation, players

In Bollywood movie *[Players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Players_(film))*, Charlie and his team foxes Spider. They move their cars having gold to a garage and move out with exact replicas of the three cars.

Next day, they fox the Russian Mafia by making three exact car replicas out of that gold.

Now my question is, how is it possible to build three new cars with gold in such a short time span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the entire car is not made with gold. The only part of the car in gold were the roof, bonnet, doors etc. I.e., the metal parts of car from outside.

The motor car garage owner, Budh Chopra, has manpower and there was pretty much between stealing gold and Russian mafia capturing them. In that duration, making those body parts was not a big deal.

Also, noticed that when Spider catches them, the mini coopers they were riding had no gold. Why? Because Charlie left the cars with gold at Chopra's garage and took replicas.

Here is the transcript:([source](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=players))

```
 So now I understand.
 You left the gold filled cars here.
 And took these empty cars.
 Great, Charlie.
```

Now, Mr. Chopra only had to make the body parts from gold.